# Model.send append

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using:

```
ranking = Ranking.create()
ranking.send("#{month}=", rank)
ranking.save!
```

I'd like to append whatever value is in the `#{month}` column, not replace it. For example, if I am performing:

```
month = 'january'

ranking.send("#{month}=", 500)
ranking.save!
```

And then again later on:

```
month = 'january'

ranking.send("#{month}=", 250)
ranking.save!
```

The value for the column `january` for that particular ranking should be 750.

Is this possible with the current ActiveRecord API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with [increment!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment-21) method

```
month = 'january'
ranking.increment!(month, 250)
```

**updated:**

to proof comments question (e.g. month = 'jan'):

```
irb(main):011:0> p.increment!(month, 70)
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "products" SET "jan" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "product
"."id" = 1  [["jan", 171], ["updated_at", Sun, 06 Oct 2013 04:23:54 UTC +00:00]

   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):012:0> p
=> #<Product id: 1, name: nil, description: nil, jan: 171, created_at: "2013-10-
06 04:22:50", updated_at: "2013-10-06 04:23:54">
```

and another case

```
irb(main):013:0> p.increment!("#{month}", 70)
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "products" SET "jan" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "products
"."id" = 1  [["jan", 241], ["updated_at", Sun, 06 Oct 2013 04:24:10 UTC +00:00]]

   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):014:0> p
=> #<Product id: 1, name: nil, description: nil, jan: 241, created_at: "2013-10-
06 04:22:50", updated_at: "2013-10-06 04:24:10">
```

Comment: Thanks! Will `month` work correctly or does it need to be called `#{month}`?

Comment: @masedesign it shoud be!

Comment: Looks like `ranking.increment("#{month}", 250)` is the only thing that works for me. If you change your answer, I'll accept!

Comment: @masedesign passing month and "#{month}" are equivalent.